# Subscriber management for Distributed Pubsub in Akka.net

Tags: publish-subscribe, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

Consider a node in a cluster who has many internal actors. Many of the actors are using Distributed Pub/Sub to subscribe to a common topic. An actor in another node in the cluster is busy posting messages onto the common topic.

Will the pub/sub system post one message to the node containing the "many actors" and then distribute the message internally across the node from there. OR will the pub/sub system send an individual message to every actor subscribed to the topic?

I suspect the forma but perhaps there is a subtly here that I don't appreciate.

Thanks,
Steven.

Comment: I think this blog post should answer your questions: https://petabridge.com/blog/distributed-pub-sub-intro-akkadotnet/

Comment: I'm aware of the article but it doesn't appear to discuss the how efficiently the cluster pub/sub system communicates messages between nodes.

Comment: Just like it's drawn in a diagram, messages are grouped and send between mediators (there's only one per node) together to avoid unnecessary network congestion. Once mediator on the other side have received them, they they will be deserialized and send in-memory to all recipients.